# A tighter bound of Vitali covering lemma for $\Bbb R^2$: $\lambda(V)\geq\frac{\lambda \left( \bigcup D_i \right) }{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I need help proving the following statement:

> Let $\{D_i\}$ be a finite colection of disks on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that there exists a subcollection of **disjoint** disks in the collection such that their union $V$ satisfies:
> $$
> \lambda(V)\geq\frac{\lambda \left( \bigcup D_i \right) }{4} .
> $$

So far the only thing I got is that it suffices to show the theorem for a set of disks that are "clustered" in the sense that there is an ennumeration of the $D_i$'s such that $$D_i\cap D_{i+1}≠\emptyset$$
And that the theorem is obviously true for up to 4 disks.

Comment: The statement you cite seems weaker than classical Vitali's lemma, which has coefficient 3 in the denominator. The proof is short and ca be found on english Wikipedia.

Comment: @JanOlszewski Weaker? Actually this is  stronger. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the original lemma would tell us that $\lambda(V) \geq \frac{1}{3^2} \lambda ( \cup D_i )$. In other words, this result tells us that we can improve the constant "a lot".

Comment: I doubt that the claim is even true. (Meanwhile have you checked Besicovith covering with best constant for the number of families?) My idea for a counterexample is to three balls of equal radii centered at the three vertices of an equilateral triangle that touch only along their boundary. The Vitali collection will be one of these as its three dilation (and 3 is sharp) will cover the other two. Then have a million baby balls that fill in (to a great deal) the remaining space in 3B. So, maybe 3^2 is actually best.